# Issue with react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I was trying to use the `react-router-dom` using this code after installing:

```
import { BrowserRouter } from react-router-dom
```

But the moment I used this code my page went blank and I don't know why.

```
<React.StrictMode>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
</React.StrictMode>
```

Comment: This isn't enough code to provide any context as to why any routed content isn't rendering as expected. Please [edit] the post to include a more complete [mcve] enough to see what is being rendered. In other words, we need to see a complete code example including imports and what routes the app is attempting to render content on.

Answer (score 0):

Did you render it through `ReactDOM` instead of `React`?

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(    <------------------ HERE ----------------
  <BrowserRouter>
    {/* The rest of your app goes here */}
  </BrowserRouter>,
  root
);
```

Comment: No i did not use react-dom

Comment: I will try it out now

Comment: I've tried it out still the same problem